# Best way to handle errors in public JSON API written in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am providing a public API to my website thats powered by PHP. However I'm really struggling with handing failures. Since others expect proper JSON then sending raw PHP errors or existing JSON with an error tacked onto the end will not work.

My first attempt

```
//The absolute first thing: get a shutdown hook and force all errors to go through it
error_reporting(0);
register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');
function handleShutdown() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if($error !== NULL)
        die(strip_tags(json_encode(array("phpError" => $error))));
}
```

Now as you can see I'm using a shutdown function instead of `set_error_handler` because some failures do not get caught by the error handler. However random errors (I don't have an exact list) still make it though and either don't get caught or just get tacked on to the end.

One of the other complications is that I can't just turn on output buffering and on an error clear everything and just print the error. This is because some methods return a huge amount of data and using output buffering would bring down the server with any sort of load.

Is there anything else I can try to wrap PHP errors in a nice JSON formatted string?

Comment: Some errors cannot be catched in any way. e.g. startup errors and syntax errors.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to return the exact error through your API. Just log the detailed error information, and send something less revealing back to the user. Leaking information could give away very detailed information about the internals of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone consuming your API *should* be paying attention to the HTTP status code that is sent with the response. As long as you are properly reporting the HTTP status codes, the body of the response is just additional information to help the consumer know *what* went wrong.

Comment: @EricBrandel - Depends on what the error is, but usually anything that would throw an exception in code would return a 500 error. Other status codes _may_ be more appropriate.

Comment: PHP throws a 500 when it encounters an error? I'm pretty sure thats not right because fatal errors can occur at any time when sending info to the user, after the headers have been sent. As I said I can't turn output buffering on to hold things back because some responses are huge by design